# Flask-login does not login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am making a text based browser game but I have a problem with my login script.
Nothing happens when I login, it doesn't even redirect.

Here is my code:

```python
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect,request,url_for,session
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user, login_user, login_required
# this contains the configuration and the database connection
from config import users, stats, register_user
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
# load the user model
from user import User


version = 2.00
app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "lkajdghdadkglajkgah"

#the user loader callback
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    u = users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    if not u:
        return None
    return User(u['_id'])

@app.route('/')
def main():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/game/", code=302)
    else:
        return redirect("/login/", code=302)

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/game/", code=302)

    # when the form is filled in
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # login user
            if request.form['logSubmit'] == 'logSubmit':
                username = request.form['logUser']
                password = request.form['logPassword']
                result = users.find_one({"user": username})

                if result and check_password_hash(result['password_hash'], password):
                    resid = result['_id']
                    print(resid)
                    user_obj = User(resid)
                    login_user(user_obj)
                    return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("game"))

        except KeyError:
            # register the user
            if request.form['regSubmit'] == 'regSubmit':
                username = request.form['regUser']
                password = request.form['regPassword']
                address = request.form['regAddress']
                register_user(username=username,password=password,address=address)
                print(address)
                return redirect("/login/", code=302)

    return render_template('out.html')

@app.route('/game/')
@login_required
def game():
    return render_template('game.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect("/login/", code=302)
```

and here is my user class:

```python
class User():

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.email = None
        print (str(id)+" has logged in.")

    #def getStats(self):
        #get the statistics of the user from the database
        #return "your getStats() is still under construction"
    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I'm looking for a couple hours now for the solution and I have a read the whole documentation of flask-login but I can't figure it out.

Please help me.

EDIT: I removed the old code and added the new code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In your `User` class you are overwriting your properties with functions. This way `user.is_authenticated` will return a function object and not the desired boolean value. In Python it is common to skip function getters/setters if it is possible. So just delete the getter functions and you should be fine.

Comment: Also your `users` object is not defined anywhere in the code. It could be a typo or imported by the * imports. I can not say clearly. That is the reason why you should avoid * imports.

Comment: @MrLeeh I tried to remove the getter functions but it still doesn't works. the users object comes indeed from config.

Comment: What info are you getting from Flask? Is `login` request completed with code 200? Did your code runs until `login_user` or fails somewhere before? Did client receives response with Set-Cookie header?

Comment: @Destiner Yes I always receive a 200 code. And login_user doesn't really fail. Nothing happens. The link in the address bars says http://localhost:1213/login/?next=%2Fgame%2F . But the redirect doesn't work and when I go to the /main/ then I am redirected back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to implement your login is with [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which handles most of the form processing for you. Also, in your `User` model, instead inherit from Flask-Login's `UserMixin` class which provides default implementations of the user methods and properties.

Comment: Thanks Achim. Didn't hear of it before. I will look into it.

Comment: You are welcome hey feel free to ask me if you have other issues

Answer (score 1):

i am going to give you code of my working login which makes use of Flask-login and Flask-WTF.

The View Function:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.get_by_username(form.username.data)
        if user is not None:
            login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
            flash("logged in successfully as {}".format(user.username))
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
        flash("Incorrect username or password")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

The Login Form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms.fields import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField,           SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, url, Length, Email, Regexp,     EqualTo, ValidationError

from models import User    
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Your Username: ', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField("Keep me logged in")
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

The User Model:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

You can implement that code in your own and see if it solves your problem